# Flutter how to know if the user is using his/her phone

Tags: flutter

Im new to flutter and i want to build and app that tracks the users usage of an app. Like starting a timer when instagram or any other app is running not in the background but actively. Are there any packages or methods to track down this like instagrams or iphones screen time feature

Comment: I don't think this is strictly related to flutter, but more generally to OS permissions in general. I don't really think that you can gather such information from one app to another.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should implement LOGIN type feature, So by this you can get the time when the user starts using your app, And before exit/close the app, add the LOGOUT action....

The difference between the successful login,logout timestamp is your user's current session usagetime....